# Indoor Navigation system using Android Accelorometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer, translate-animation, indoor-positioning-system

I am working on an Android app , where i can setup an indoor navigation system of my building. I am using Accelorometer sensor to develop the system. But i am little stuck in movement of the navigation arrow.  The arrow is not moving.

**MyCode:**

```
package com.sample.accelerometer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager senSensorManager;
private Sensor senAccelerometer;

private long lastUpdate = 0;
private float last_x, last_y, last_z;

TextView textView;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.act);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    senSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
            long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            last_x = x;
            last_y = y;
            last_z = z;

            textView.setText("X = "+x+" ,Y = "+y+" , Z  = "+z);
            AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

            TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.ABSOLUTE,-last_x, Animation.ABSOLUTE,last_x,
                    Animation.ABSOLUTE,-last_y, Animation.ABSOLUTE,last_y);
            a.setDuration(1000);
            animationSet.addAnimation(a);
            imageView.startAnimation(animationSet);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
}
```

[image]

This is my above code , please suggest me some solution to move the arrow in the navigation direction.

Comment: hum, are you sure that you can do it with `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` ? that should tell you how the device is moving but not it's absolute position in space

Comment: you must try to find the sensor which can give you azimuth. Azimuth is the rotation of device around z axis with respect to true north.

Comment: Great thanks, i can try with Azimuth , i think this will also relates to compass , i can try this too